# Can the Enterprise Service Bus in SOA be replaced by multiple service bus implementations and still be SOA?

Tags: design, microservices, soa

When and Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) is designed, and the ESB is changed to multiple independent service busses that talk to each other (pub/sub), does the architecture cease to be SOA?  Is it then a blend between Microservices and SOA?  Full Microservice?

SOA has "bounded contexts" it seems to me, though I usually don't see them called that, but is the only difference the Enterprise Service Bus as opposed to the bounded contexts of Microservices separated by independent service busses.

I understand the problems they are trying to solve with decoupling, using an API, and the rest, but the architecture doesn't look too different outside of the single ESB.  Can SOA have more than one service bus and still be SOA?  Is it there is a single API as well with that ESB?

Edit:

I found this from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/topics/esb#:%7E:text=In%20any%20case%20the%20enterprise,having%20a%20bunch%20of%20services.):

"In any case the enterprise service bus shields the new application from the legacy interface. An ESB performs the necessary transformation and routing to connect to the legacy system service. It is possible to implement a SOA without an ESB architecture, but this would be equivalent to just having a bunch of services."

Is "a bunch of services" the same as Microservices?

Comment: Do you consider an ESB to be an essential component of SOA?  I don't.

Comment: Yes but only because of all the diagrams.  Do you mean leave out all busses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not know how to be clearer.  I apologize.  Without service bus, is it SOA?  One big service bus?  Many?

Comment: @JohnMar I would argue that unless you have specific problems that an ESB can help you solve, you are better off without one (or more than one.)  The main scenario where I would consider an ESB would be a complex set of heterogenous legacy systems to integrate.  And honestly, my experience with using ESBs puts them pretty low on my list of preferences.  I'm not saying they can't or don't add value but that you can get these features in other ways without adopting bloatware (IMO.)  Anyway, I don't think the number of ESBs involved has any bearing on whether you can call something SOA.